# Is there any way to set google form answer formatting as plain text?

Tags: text, google-apps-script, format

I needed this for my school project, but I'm quite confused.

I tried things like getting range of cells in answer sheet with

```
function format{ 
   var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
   var main = sheet.getSheetByName("answers");
   var ad = main.getRange("A1:BH3000").getGridId();

   .....
```

Now I would probably use the

```
   Logger.log(ad);
```

but then, I don't really know what to use. The best would probably be

```
   copyFormatToRange();
```

but I don't really know how to use it. Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 0):

Call [`setNumberFormat('@STRING@')`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setNumberFormat(String)) on your range. That should set the formatting on the specified range to plain text.